# background-color property on changed class not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

This might be a stupid question, but I searched it on the internet, even on Stack Overflow, but I am not able to understand the problem. The code is very basic:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>DOCUMENT OBJECT MODEL</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li class="sameClass" style="background-color:black; color:white; margin:5px; ">ONE</li>
            <li class="sameClass" style="background-color:black; color:white; margin:5px ">TWO</li>
            <li class="sameClass" style="background-color:orange; color:red; margin:5px">THREE</li>
            <li class="sameClass" style="background-color:orange; color:red; margin:5px">FOUR & FIVE</li>
        </ul>
        <div id="getValues"></div>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
li.differentClass{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

JS:

```
var element = document.querySelector("li.sameClass");
element.className = "differentClass";
```

Now, the script changes the className of the first list item, that is understood. And in the style sheet, list item with className "differentClass" will have its appearance changed. For example, in the CSS, I write something like this:

```
li.differentClass{
    border:solid 5px pink;
}
```

This works without any problem. But, have a look at my original code. The list item with className "differentClass" shall have its background-color changed to orange. But that's not working. Not only that, but properties like "color" is also not changing.

What is the problem?

Comment: It is probably because you are not removing the inline styles. Inline styles override external CSS.

Comment: Might it be an issue with `style` tag? Likely the class is being overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
li.differentClass{
background-color:orange !important;
}
```

And I recommend reading this: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Good link, but try to avoid using `!important` if you can. TylerH is right in the comments, you need to avoid inline styles.

Comment: @gaynorvader It's the only pure css way to override inline style.

Comment: @Nick Yep, but a far better solution would be to not use inline styles in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used `inline` CSS property then to change any style other than inline property, you can use class which add those property to element but for changing inline property use `style` property of element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/er_sarjan/0j4fvq82/)

For Example:

```
element.style.backgroundColor = "red"; // To override inline property
```

But for adding font-size or other property, which are not set by inline css you can use `class`

```
// CSS
li.differentClass{
    border:solid 5px pink;
}

//JS
element.className = "differentClass"; // To add property which are not set by inline css
```

Comment: Yeah... Thnx for the tips